# Android build has white image over game

Tags: unity, 2d, image, bug

In unity when I am playing my game it displays fine, but when I build and run it to my nexus 5 there is this white something I don't even know over my game. Any suggestions for fixes?[image]

[image]

Comment: can you include a screenshot of what it looks like from Unity?

Comment: Yes sure thing.

Comment: Its up and ready to be viewed

Comment: I am not sure. It is hard to tell because of the colors.  It might be something in the Canvas because I've seen scaling things like that happen on my nexus. I use Canvas "scale with screensize" and I make sure my anchor points are at the corners of my graphics.

Comment: I use the screensize scaling also im gonna see and fix some potential mishaps with anchors and ill come back to you

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know why, but I just put the z value to 1 for quad and it made it work I just thought half the screen was in front and half was behind so if i made it 1 it would level it out. Thats probably not the reasoning but give it a try if you have half the screen as your quad.